# Assingning Refrences in Java

Tags: java

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}

public class Test {
     public static void main(String [] args){
    A a = new A();
    A b = new B();
    A c = new C();

    a = b;
    b = c;
    }
}
```

Here how can we assign child reference to parent one ? and also b and c are different object types then how we can assign one to another ?

Comment: `b` and `c` are _references_ of the same type: `A` and even if they reference objects of different types they still can be assigned to one another since all that's required is that the referenced objects are instances of `A`. Besides that, what does "child reference" mean? Do you mean a reference of a subclass/superclass type?

Answer (score 2):

`a`, `b` and `c` are variables of type `A`, which means they can hold references to objects of class `A` or any sub-class of `A`, which includes the classes `B` and `C`.

When you write

```
b = c;
```

you are not assigning an an object of class `C` to a variable of class `B` (which wouldn't pass compilation), you are assigning a reference to an object of class `C` (held by the `c` variable) to a variable of class `A`.

Comment: public class A { }
public class B extends A { }
public class C extends A { }                                                                       List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();                                                              listA = listB;   listB = listA; why this is not valid then

Comment: @VipinDubey Because `ArrayList<B>` is not a sub class of `ArrayList<A>`.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we assign child reference to parent one?

In object-oriented concepts, when you say `class B extends A` then `class B` maintains **IS-A** relationship with `class A`. So you can assign the B object to the reference as type A.

> b and c are different object types then how we can assign one to
>   another?

Even though they are different types, because `class B` **IA-A** type of `class A` and `class C` (also) **IS-A** type of `class A` (in terms of their relationship), so you can assign both B & C objects to reference type A.

But **one important point is that you can't call any of the `B`'s specific members (methods/fields) with reference type `A` pointing to object `B`** i.e., you can ONLY call `A`'s members with reference type `A` (even though object is of `B`).

Answer (score 1):

Because of polymorphism and inheritance. When you say that;

```
class Manager extends Worker{}
```

Actually you say, all Manager is a Worker. But Manager is more spesific type than Worker. For this reason we use the `extends` keyword for inheritance. Every Manager is a Worker but more detailed Worker.

```
Worker o1 = new Worker();
Worker o2 = new Manager();
o1 = o2;
```

In first line, `o1` is a worker Object (general type). 
Second line is an example of upcasting. This line say that:  `o2` is a manager object but o2's interface is worker's interface.
In third line, because every manager is a worker, you can assign a manager object to a worker type reference.